# How can we remove the duplicates in async function of java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, duplicates

I am taking the data from backend for that I am using the async function.
But the data contains some duplicate elements so I need to remove them and get those data in DOM.
Can we do that. If yes can you explain how to do that.

```
function Productpage(){
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    
    let getproducts = async () => {
        
        let res = await axios.get(`${env.apiurl}/users/products`)
        console.log(data)
        if (res.data.statusCode === 200) {
          setData(res.data.data)
        }
        else {
          alert(res.data.message)
        }
      }
      console.log(data)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getproducts()
      }, [])

  return <>
  <div>
      {
      data.map((e,i)=>{
        return <div key={i} onClick={()=>navigate(`${e.producttype}`)} >
            <Card style={{width:"100%", height:"250px"}}>
                <CardImg
                alt="Card image cap"
                src={e.url}
                top
                width="50%"
                height="60%"
                />
                <CardBody>
                <CardTitle tag="h5">
                    {e.producttype}
                </CardTitle>              
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
            </div>
      })
      }
      </div>
    </>
    
}
```

Here data comes from backend and from that data only needed to print partcular values like url and product type in DOM only **without any duplicate values for the product type**.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your question has nothing to do with `async` or nodejs or react. It's just about getting rid of duplicates (in a list of strings). And, ironically, that summarizes this thread very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/5767484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove duplicate elements by first creating a hashmap.

```
// Will have structure like {car: {}, paint: {}, toy: {}}
// Retains the LAST element in the list for each product type
const hashMap = res.data.data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return {...acc, [cur.producttype]: cur}; 
}, {});

setData(Object.values(hashMap));
```

However, probably the best way is to add support for this query on the api side. So you don't have to send a ton of data over the wire just to throw it out. Something like `users/products?distinctKey=producttype`

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of product types and ignore any items that are already in the set:

```
const dataWithoutDuplicates = [];
const encounteredProductTypes = new Set();
for(const item of data) {
  if(encounteredProductTypes.has(item.producttype) continue;
  dataWithoutDuplicates.push(item);
  encounteredProductTypes.add(item.producttype);
}
```